# Incorporate the date into filename

Tags: sas

I have a report need to send other sharedrive, need to send title and the date. How can I do that

```
     PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.ARG_REPORT
        OUTFILE= "/dwdata/sas_data/REPORT.csv" REPLACE;

  RUN;
```

what can i add to REPORT for see the date? thaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a macro variable with the date especially if the date will change depending on when you run the code. Then reference that variable in the export statement.
The code below grabs today's date.

```
%let numdate = %sysfunc(today(), yymmddn8.);

PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.ARG_REPORT
            OUTFILE= "/dwdata/sas_data/REPORT_&numdate..csv"  
            DBMS=CSV  REPLACE;
RUN;
```

Comment: Double dot needed for &numdate, or you'll end up with a file called REPORT_01MAY2014CSV.

Comment: Yes.. macro variable needs the double dot. Thank you

Comment: If you have multiple files, then instead of the `date9.` format you could use `yymmddn8.` so the files are automatically sorted in chronological order.

Comment: Learning awesome tips here... edited to yymmddn8. Thank you Robert.

Comment: this is awesome! %let numdate = %sysfunc(today(), yymmddn8.);  but how can i use this to subtract a number of days..for example if i run on a tuesday, i want the file name to be friday ending. Thanks!